# How to serve a CSV file with flask without downloading?

Tags: python, csv, flask

I'm trying to create a flask endpoint that will return a CSV file, without downloading it. For example, something like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/3d-scatter.csv),  where the CSV is viewable on the webpage itself.

This is the current code I am using:

```
@app.route("/csv")
def get_csv():
    return send_file('data.csv', as_attachment=True)
```

I have tried with both `as_attachment=True` and `as_attachment=False` but both just cause the page to automatically download the data.csv file to my computer. How can I stop the csv from downloading it, and display it on the page instead?

Comment: You'd use jinga to render the csv in html just like any other page. That means the html page will be downloaded by the browser - because everything you see in your browser is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`Response`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Response.html) :

```
from flask import Response

@app.route("/csv")
def get_csv():
    with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
    return Response(content, mimetype="text/plain")
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't know how to display CSV files, so it's downloading it as an attachment. Use the `mimetype` argument to tell it to treat it as plain text.

```
return send_file('data.csv', as_attachment=False, mimetype='text/plain')
```

Comment: This still causes it to download for me

Comment: Instead of using `send_file()` try reading the file into a variable and send that as text.